# PHP cannot receive a String from Android

Tags: java, php, android

The following code attempts to POST a String from Android to PHP.

- INTERNET permission is given.
- Shark has been checked.
- the device connects to MAMP (WAMP for MAC) server and sends the String.

Code on Android:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://MAMP-SERVER/post.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "Andro"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    httpclient.execute(post);
    Log.i("POSTED", "YOUR USERNAME");

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.e("Client Protocol Exception", "Err "+ e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("IO Exception","Err "+ e.getMessage());
}
```

Code on PHP:

```
$test=$_REQUEST["username"];  print $_REQUEST["username"];
```

Comment: Try `$_POST` or `$_GET` since `$_REQUEST` doesn't always work. `$_REQUEST` is considered to be a code smell.

Comment: Have you tried setting `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? (eg: `post.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')` )

Comment: Frits- thanx, tried that.

Comment: NullUserException- what does it mean?

Comment: @AndroHead It's the default content type for a `POST`ed form. PHP's `$_POST` won't work without it. AFAIK HttpClient doesn't add this header, so you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: ok... added it, but nothing.

Comment: What are you expecting, and what's actually happening?

Comment: May be I got it all wrong. I'm sending the String to the php, and waiting that it will appear on the screen- is it ok?

Comment: @AndroHead Appear on what screen? Don't tell me you have a browser window open `http://MAMP-SERVER/post.php` and you're expecting it to show the username posted by Java, because that's not going to happen. That's just not how things work.

Comment: :/ So... how can I see it on the screen?

Comment: You have to get the response from the server then display it within the app. You need to look up some tutorials and the documentation, you're far from getting it working with this example.

Comment: You should use [RAW POST DATA](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php).

Comment: mmm... so, I'm sitting infront of my screen for nothing...

Comment: @AndroHead So, do you have a browser window open or not? If  by "screen" you mean you're looking at the browser, then yes, it's for nothing.

Comment: Thanx guys... I feel kind os stupid, but In the other hand I know nothing in PHP, so- less stupid :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$test=$_POST["username"];  print $_POST["username"];
```

?

Comment: yap, tried also $_GET, and even to send the Var inside the "HTTPPOST".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're actually posting the data?

You could try sending the POST request more like below methods. Then you should be able to simply get your value in the PHP with $_POST

```
public void execute(final RequestMethod method)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    switch (method) {
    case GET:
        // add parameters
        String combinedParams = "";
        if (!params.isEmpty()) {
            combinedParams += "?";
            for (NameValuePair p : params) {
                String paramString = p.getName() + "="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(), "UTF-8");

                if (combinedParams.length() > 1) {
                    combinedParams += "&" + paramString;
                } else {
                    combinedParams += paramString;
                }
            }
        }
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(remoteUrl + combinedParams);
        // add headers
        for (NameValuePair h : headers) {
            getRequest.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
        }
        executeRequest(getRequest, remoteUrl);
        break;
    case POST:
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(remoteUrl);
        // add headers
        for (NameValuePair h : headers) {
            postRequest.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
        }
        if (!params.isEmpty()) {
            postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                    (List<? extends NameValuePair>) params, HTTP.UTF_8));
        }
        executeRequest(postRequest, remoteUrl);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

And

```
private void executeRequest(final HttpUriRequest request, final String url) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpResponse httpResponse;

    try {
        httpResponse = client.execute(request);
        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        errorMessage = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            responseStream = entity.getContent();

            if (!needStreamInsteadOfString) {
                response = convertStreamToString(responseStream);

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                responseStream.close();
            }
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```